# Why did my boarding pass have to be manually checked at the gate?

Tags: passports

I recently travelled from the US to the UK with my friends for a trip, during boarding, my boarding pass and one of my friend's boarding pass was rejected by the scanner at the gate during boarding and we had to step aside while they manually checked our boarding passes and passports. On the flight back to the US, the same thing happened again but only to my boarding pass this time and it took them longer to manually check it this time. What could've possibly happened to set off the scanner?

Comment: Your passport was rejected by the gate? It is unusual for passports to be "scanned" at boarding gates in either the US or the UK. Are you sure it was not your boarding pass that was rejected?

Comment: Ah actually I think you're right it was the boarding pass that was rejected, but they did ask for my passport and the boarding pass to manually check it again.

Comment: Did you check in online? Did you check in any bags? Had anyone from the airline [not including airport security] actually looked at your passport before you got to the gate?

Comment: Yeah we all had checked in online and all had 1 checked bag both ways. And while checking in our baggage, they did check all of our passports too before printing our boarding passes. All of us did the exact same thing basically but only 2 of us had issues with the boarding pass on the way to the UK and only I had an issue on the way back.

Comment: Maybe you folded it or the print was smudged? I see that very seldom, and then it is the (non-)quality of the printed card that makes them check.

Comment: There are a number of reasons your boarding pass can have a "NOT OK" status after it has been ok'd by the check-in desk. Any answer would be fairly speculative.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't sure if there was a single more common reason that others might've consistently experienced. I guess I was just the unlucky one both times then.